# Do containers respawn?

Tags: dead-island

Do any of the containers (specifically the locked ones) in dead island respawn?

Is it possible to farm a level 3 locked chest over and over again in hopes of good stuff?

Comment: Before I answer this question, I just have to ask: I have fully upgraded my lockpicking, and since I have, I've never seen a locked chest. I assumed I would have to actually unlock chests, but does having the required lockpicking just remove the notification of what level lock it is, and allow you to open it like normal?

Comment: Just tested this - I stood in front of a level 2 locked chest and upgraded my lockpick skill from level 1 to level 2. When I looked at the chest the "lockpick level 2 required" disappeared entirely leaving only the "open" command. So yeah, it removes the notification.

Comment: Ok, good, I can make my answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to farm the containers over and over.

One of the first containers that I noticed which was locked was a level 2 container (I think it was on the back of an ambulance truck or something), and I looted it about 5 different times as I was passing it before I moved on to the next area.

With that said, since you can't tell if a container is meant to be locked or not (unless you're playing co-op with someone who doesn't have the skill), it'll be fairly hard to figure out which ones to farm, unless you luck out and get something really good the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Through experience I found that during the 'Boat Supplies' Main Quest, the Red Container that you get the 'Package' from has a Level 3 Chest. I farmed off this one, then headed back to the boat. Directly east of the boat (Where three punks are) is another Level 3 Chest, you can farm this one too. To respawn them, the only efficient way I found was to enter the sewers, then exit. After that, I just went back after them, gaining one Legendary Weapon (**McCall's 9mm**) in four days (a total of 30 hours of playing). I dont know if it changes from console to console, but I did it on **PS3**.

Answer (score -1):

Containers don't seem to respawn much, actually. You can fast travel around the world, run around for however long you'd like, and the containers will remain opened. The only occasions that they reset is when you re-load your save, join another player, or drop out from another players game. This is because all of these instances will re-load the world, thus resetting containers.

Comment: This has not been my experience: I have seen containers respawn frequently, although in general I believe you need to move from one area to another to trigger respawning.

Answer (score -1):

yep did it like 50 times do in the bunkers #1 #2 in resort works on Xbox 360